# Static variable of superclass acting weird in subclass-creation

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, static, subclass

I'm working on a classic homework program and cannot for the life of me figure out why my static variable in the superclass reacts the way it does..

The program is a bankaccount where I have created a superclass, Account, and two subclasses, CreditAccount and SavingsAccount.

```
public abstract class Account {

  private double balance;
  private int accountId;
  **private static int lastAssignedNumber = 1000;**  <--- the static int
  private String accountType;

  public Account (double q_balance, String q_accountType)
  { 
    balance = q_balance;
    accountType = q_accountType;
    **accountId = ++lastAssignedNumber; <------ counter for new accountId**
  }

)

public class CreditAccount extends Account {

  public CreditAccount(double balance) 
  {
    super(balance, "Creditaccount");
  }

}

public class SavingsAccount extends Account {

  public SavingsAccount(double balance) 
  {
    super(balance, "Savingsaccount");
  }

}
```

Previously, without subclasses when Account was the only object, the counter worked beautifully. But now when I create some new objects of savingsaccount and creditaccounts the program acts really weird and returns accountnumbers as follows:

```
           new SavingsAccount(0);   // **1001**
    new CreditAccount(0);   // **1001**
    new CreditAccount(0);   // **1002**
    new SavingsAccount(0); // **1003**
    new CreditAccount(0);   // **1002**
    new CreditAccount(0);   // **1004**
    new SavingsAccount(0); // **1005**
```

What in gods name is happening?! What am I missing? Shouldn't the two subclasses provoke the same static variable 'lastAssignedNumber' and add to it accordingly??

Kindest regards // Gewra

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?  The pre- and post-increment operators are not atomic, so operations performed across multiple threads might interleave and produce unexpected results like those.

Comment: You should probably synchronize those.

Comment: Can you post where you're actually creating these various accounts, as well as how you're retrieving their `accountId`s?

Comment: could you make lastAssignedNumber into an AtomicInteger (which you get get and increment as a single operation) and see if this goes away?

Comment: Like @Alan said, if you are using multiple threads then you need to declare lastAssignedNumber volatile (there are of course a myriad other ways of ensuring that the same number doesn't get distributed twice or more but that is left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: @Erik: Making it volatile won't make the ++ operation atomic. An AtomicInteger is a better choice.

Comment: @Erik - increments in Java are **not** atomic, they involve a read and a write. The `volatile` keyword will not help with that; they have to be syncronized or done via AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code , given that you are creating accounts in **single thread model**.
Your following code is working absolutely fine:

```
abstract class Account 
{

    private double balance;
    private int accountId;
    private static int lastAssignedNumber = 1000;
    private String accountType;

    public Account (double q_balance, String q_accountType)
    { 
        balance = q_balance;
        accountType = q_accountType;
        accountId = ++lastAssignedNumber;
    }
    public int getAccountID()
    {
        return accountId;
    }

}
class CreditAccount extends Account 
{
    public CreditAccount(double balance) 
    {
        super(balance, "Creditaccount");
    }

}
class SavingsAccount extends Account 
{
    public SavingsAccount(double balance) 
    {
        super(balance, "Savingsaccount");
    }
}
public class AccountLedger
{
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Account ac[] = new Account[7];
        ac[0] = new SavingsAccount(0); //1001  
        ac[1] = new CreditAccount(0);  //1002  
        ac[2] = new CreditAccount(0);  //1003  
        ac[3] = new SavingsAccount(0); //1004  
        ac[4] = new CreditAccount(0);  //1005  
        ac[5] = new CreditAccount(0);  //1006  
        ac[6] = new SavingsAccount(0); //1007  
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ac.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ac[i].getAccountID());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concepts of multi- and singlethreading are frankly completely new to me but I've tried making both an AtomicInteger and a volatile variable with the exactly same result. I guess it's my structure of the program that is fundamentaly wrong.

The construct is a BankLogic-class holding an ArrayList of Customer-objects. The Customer-objects hold an ArrayList of Account-objects. It doesn't matter where I put the AtomicInteger-object, even though I put it in the BankLogic-class and pass it through to the constructor, it still turns out the same results.

Guess I should just place the accounts-ArrayList in the BankLogic-class and run a method comparing personal-ids (adding a persId-variable to the account-class) instead?
It certainly doesn't feel like such an elegant solution but I see no other way.

Thanks for all the answers!